# How to simulate a Date comparison with String representing dd/mm/yyyy in J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me

There is a Date-like String data from a csv String data, that is the Date-like String data has a form of `dd/mm/yyyy`. I want to implement a method which compares two Date-like String data like if I compare two Date objects. How to achieve that in J2ME ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare the Strings by comparing the individual substrings year-first like there:

```
public int compare(String date1, String date2) {
  int year = date1.substring(6).compareTo(date2.substring(6));
  if (year == 0) {
     int month = date1.substring(3,5).compareTo(date2.substring(3,5));
     if (month == 0) {
       return date1.substring(0,2).compareTo(date2.substring(0,2));
     } else {
       return month;
     }
  } else {
     return year;
  }
}
```

This works even in MIDP, although I would agree, it is not the solution winning any beauty-contest.

Comment: you could directly order the strings to format "yyyymmdd" and compare them, if you want to increase the beauty ;)

Comment: Thought about this as well, however, the order-changing code would be equally ugly. So encapsulation is the order of the day.

Comment: +1 ... but it ain't pretty.  I'd actually prefer to write a bespoke parse method to turn the Strings into Dates and then compare them.  At least that way you know you're comparing valid dates.

Comment: While you were right adding the closing bracket at `compareto` I consider it highly impolite to change my style of code indenting. This is a question of my personal style as this is my answer. Go ahead write your own in your style, but please leave mine alone